# How do you control import order in an R package documented with roxygen2?

Tags: r, import, roxygen2

`roxygen2` will automatically build a `NAMESPACE` file based on my `@import` directives in my package documentation. But apparently, it doesn't matter how I order the `@import` directives, it always adds the imports in alphabetical order.

This causes me problems: I am working on a package that needs to import both `IRanges` and `data.table`. Both of these packages define a function called `shift`, so the import order matters (the `shift` function in the environment will come from the last loaded package).

In my roxygen2 code, I say:

```
@import data.table
@import IRanges
```

I put `data.table` first because I want the `shift` function from `IRanges` to override the one from `data.table` But the order of the `@import` lines doesn't seem to matter, as `roxygen2` always puts into the `NAMESPACE` file import lines with `IRanges` first. Then I get this message:

> 2: replacing previous import 'IRanges::shift' by 'data.table::shift'
>   when loading...

I want it to be the other way around; but really, even if I happened to get lucky here, I'd rather not rely on alphabetical ordering for something to work. Is there any way to control this?

Edit: I believe `data.table` comes after `IRanges` because the the `I` is capitalized.

Comment: Why don't you call the functions by `data.table::shift` and `IRanges::shift`?

Comment: Yes I can do that, and that is what I am doing. That is a basic solution for this immediate example, but does the bigger picture question about import order have an answer?

Comment: Being explicit with pkgname::funname isn't just a "basic solution" - it's just better to be explicit precisely to avoid conflicts. Don't depend on import order or anything else. Be explicit.You'll thank yourself six months from now when you go back and wonder where functions came from.